# How do I send emails using django-simple-email-confirmation?

Tags: python, django, email

I have just started using [django-simple-email-confirmation](https://github.com/mfogel/django-simple-email-confirmation). They have an example of how to use it, which invokes a `send_email` method, as below:

```
email = 'original@here.com'
user = User.objects.create_user(email, email=email)
user.is_confirmed # False

send_email(email, 'Use %s to confirm your email' % user.confirmation_key)
# User gets email, passes the confirmation_key back to your server
```

I was wondering where this `send_email` method came from. I can't find it by [searching the repo](https://github.com/mfogel/django-simple-email-confirmation/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=send_email), besides when they use it in this example (which does not import anything). Everybody else seems to use the `send_mail` method in django, so I was wondering what exactly was going on here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `send_email` in the example looks like a typo. It looks to me as if they are using [`send_mail`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/email/#send-mail) from Django. Try adding the following import:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
```

Then change the code in the example to use `send_mail` instead of `send_email`.

```
send_email(email, 'Use %s to confirm your email' % user.confirmation_key)
```

Comment: May be a dumb question, but why would `send_email` work by importing `send_mail`?

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't spotted the difference between `send_mail` and `send_email`. My guess is that `send_email` in the example is a typo, and it should use `send_mail` instead. It might be a better idea to ask the authors if you want a definitive answer.